# Single Table Inheritance with Join Table has_one association is returning a method_missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations, single-table-inheritance

I'm having a problem getting my data model to work correctly.

I have the following models and sub models.

```
class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :connection
has_one :trainer, :through => :connection
has_one :owner, :through => :connection
end

class User < ActiverRecord::Base    #Single table inheritance
has_many :connections
has_many :horses, :through => :connections
end

class Owner < User
#owner specific code
end

class Trainer < User
#trainer specific code
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base #join table
belongs_to :horse
belongs_to :owner
belongs_to :trainer
end
```

I have successfully created horses, owners, trainers and connections with all the type fields populated correctly. When I type Horse.all at the console it returns all horses as expected. The same is true of User.all Connections.all Trainer.all and Owner.all.

Now, however, I'm trying to do something like. Horse.trainer and Horse.owner to return the trainer and owner for the horse.  When I attempt this I am getting a method_missing error.  I thought that the associations I created would allow this to work.  I've been banging my head on the wall now for quite a while so if anyone can offer any insight or guidance I would appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I noticed your Horse model has the :through => :connections call, while having one connection. Remove the s and see what happens.

Comment: Srdjan - Thanks.  I made the correction, but I'm still getting the missing_method error.

Comment: Can you update the code example here? Also, Connections model should be Connection (no s). It should also belong to Owner and Trainer. It's a join model, so it has to make that connection.

Comment: Try dropping user_ from user_owner and user_trainer.

Comment: Made the change and then tried horse.trainer and Horse.trainer and I continue to get the undefined method / missing_method error.

Comment: Am I missing an association between connection and user? Or is that implied through the sub classes

Comment: I was hoping Rails would resolve it, but I guess not. Try moving the has_many through code Trainer and Owner. I'll expand in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
class Trainer < User
  has_many :connections
  has_many :horses, :through => :connections
end
```

Do the same for Owner. That should connect the associations once and for all.

Comment: I thought this would have done it, but I'm still getting the same error.  Am I correct that I don't need to migrate after this change because the sub classes don't have tables.

Comment: As long as there's a user_id field in the connections table, there shouldn't need to be any migrations. Can you verify that there's data in that table and that that data is correct?

Comment: Yes, there is valid data in the database. By the way, I really appreciate your help on this. thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'll set up an example app with these models in the morning, as I need to see this running in order to help you solve it.

Comment: Wow! That would be wonderful. I truly appreciate it.  I'm planning on taking another crack at it myself later today.  Thanks again.

Comment: You know, I've been thinking. I don't think you need a has_many :through here. Correct me if I'm wrong, but description of your intent here is that the Horse belongs to an Owner and a Trainer and an Owner can have many Horses. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct and a trainer can also train many horses.  Also, I have the connections join table because its important to also be able to look at the different owner/trainer pairs as a single entity. My aim is to be able to analyze Trainer/Horse dynamics, Owner/Horse dynamics and (Owner/Trainer)/Horse dynamics.   If that makes any sense.

Comment: I kinda understand what you want to do, but you don't need the join model. The thing making this hard is that has_one :through and has_many :through don't behave as one would expect; Also, if you pivot your viewpoint to that of the Horse, since it relates to both Owner and Trainer, you still should be able to do your analysis.

Comment: I'll try dropping the join table to see if this works. My aim was to have the join table (Connections) encapsulate owner and trainer.  In doing so I thought I could reduce the number of foreign keys in for example a RaceData table.  With the join table, the RaceData table would include a horse_id, finish position and connection_id. If I wanted to determine the trainer I could do something like connection.trainer. I also get the added benefit of being able to look at the Owner/Trainer pair  Without the join table the RaceData table will include horse_id, finish position, trainer_id and Owner_id

Comment: Yeah, see, the way relational data is modelled, has_many :through really means you've two models whose relationship is many-to-many. The only difference is that you want to track additional data.

What you have is a two one-to-many relationships and as such, you only need has_many :horses and belongs_to :owner and belongs_to :trainer. All other analysis has to be done through a join.

Now, if you want to consider a document-oriented database, like Mongo, you'll be able to store all of that under the Trainer or Owner document. It'll make analysis easier.